# Volume Generated by rotating the region $y=2x-x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

What is the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region $y=2x-x^2$, $y=1$, $x=0$, $x=2$ about $y=1$?

Edit: Here is what I have done. But I'm not sure if I'm correct
[What I have done So far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCmjw.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Attach your current working

Comment: @StephenDonovan I have attached my current work, and I have come up with some answer but I'm just not sure

Comment: @Prometheus I have attached my current work

Comment: Your setup actually looks correct, I think you may have slipped on the integration though. I suggest rewriting the integrand as $(x - 1)^4,$ and then you can simply use the substitution $u = x - 1, du = dx$ and integrate pretty simply. (sorry if it feels like I'm teasing you forward, I'm doing this now because you're actually really close and I think it might be good for you to try to finish on your own if possible)

Comment: It is unclear to me what is the dimensionality of the problem.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thanks. I found $2\pi/5$

Comment: I get $\frac{2\pi}5$ as well, that should be correct. Good job

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, no problem. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where you left off:

$$\pi \int_0^2 (1 - (2x-x^2))^2 \ dx = \pi \int_0^2 (x-1)^4\ dx$$
$$= \pi \left[\frac{1}{5}(x-1)^5 \right]_0^2 = \frac{\pi}{5} (1^5 - (-1)^5) = \frac{2 \pi}{5} $$

If you prefer, you can use a $u$-substution but you will need to change the bounds. Intutively, since we multiply by $\frac{d}{dx} x = 1$ to differentiate $(x-1)^4$, we divide by $1$ to integrate $(x-1)^4$ as usual (the formal proof comes from the chain rule). This allows you to find $\int (2x-1)^4 \ dx$ and so on.